# system() not working

Tags: c, system

I am trying to launch executables from a C source file. When there is a space in the path I.e.

```
system("D:\\Games\\Subway Surfers\\Subway_Surfers.exe")
```

it does not work but 
when I change the folder name and remove the space it works. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Because all tools are horribly broken. Never use spaces in file names.

Comment: You can escape the space with a \ before it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `\` with `\\` and   with `\`. You have to replace the characters with their respective escape characters.

```
system("\"D:\\Games\\Subway\ Surfers\\Subway_Surfers.exe\"");
```

This command would be interpreted as:

```
"D:\Games\Subway Surgers\Subway_Surfers.exe"
```

And, the quotes around the path with spaces ensure that the string is not truncated about the space.

Comment: `\ ` would be interpreted by the c compiler as a space. Possibly quotes around the file name would work.

Comment: You mean, `system("\"D:...\"");` ?

Comment: That's what I mean. That is the normal way to execute programs which include a space in the file name under windows. Haven't tried it though. Otherwise a caret (`^`) to escape the space could work too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use escape characters while using spaces in path.

Ex:  `system("D:\\Games\\Subway\ Surfers\\Subway_Surfers.exe");`

Comment: `\ ` would be interpreted by the c compiler as a space. Possibly quotes around the file name would work.

Comment: `system("D:\Games\\"Subway Surfers\"\Subway_Surfers.exe")`.. like this? I suppose this should also work..

Comment: quotes around the whole file name. See my comment at the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys escape characters didn't work so I just used CreateProcess() function. Its long but works fine even with spaces

Comment: `CreateProcess()` is probably better too to use under windows. It gives you more control over the process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote subdir name containing space character. For example like
`system("D:\\Games\\\"Subway Surfers\"\\Subway_Surfers.exe")`  where \"Subway Surfers\" is quoted subdir with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a perfect workaround to use the system() function. it requires a string in the argument so i just create a string whose contents are the path e.g char path[50] = "D:\SubwaySurfers\SubwaySurfers.exe" then call the function as

system(path);

however in some specific applications such as Apache(Game) it doesnt work whether i use CreateProcess or System.